# Problema con calculadora en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema:

A la hora de poner el resultado por pantalla no consigo que me lo ponga. El problema es que no se me imprime el resultado en el input que corresponde. No puedo ver el error en la consola ni nada.

Éste es el código:

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: text/html; Charset=UTF-8'); 
$num1 = null;
$num2 = null;
$resultado = null;

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
     $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
     $operacion = $_POST['operacion'];
     $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
     if ($operacion == '+') {
            $resultado = $num1 + $num2;
        } else if ($operacion == '-') {
            $resultado =  $num1 - $num2;
        } else if (operacion == '*') {
            $resultado =  $num1 * $num2;
        } else if ($operacion == '/') {
            $resultado =  $num1 / $num2;
        } else if ($operacion == '%') {
            $resultado =  $num1 % $num2;
    } 
}
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="num1" name="num1" >
    <select name="operacion" id="operacion" name="operacion">
        <option disabled selected>Operacion</option>
        <option>+</option>
        <option>-</option>
        <option value="*">x</option>
        <option>/</option>
        <option value="%">Módulo</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" />
    <input type="number" name="resultado" id="resultado" disabled /><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Porque `$resultado` es una variable de php que no estás luego pasándolo por pantalla, sólo lo estás recogiendo. Con `echo $resultado;` deberías verlos, lo que tendrás que controlar qué aparece cuando no se está calculando nada.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Todo funciona perfecto. Saludos

```html
<?php
header ('Content-Type: text/html; Charset=UTF-8'); 
$num1 = null;
$num2 = null;
$operacion = '+';
$resultado = null;

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
   $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
   $operacion = $_POST['operacion'];
   $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
   if ($operacion == '+') {
    $resultado =  $num1 + $num2;
    }
    else if ($operacion == '-') {
        $resultado =  $num1 - $num2;
    } else if ($operacion == '*') {
        $resultado =  $num1 * $num2;
    } else if ($operacion == '/') {
        $resultado =  $num1 / $num2;
    } else if ($operacion == '%') {
        $resultado =  $num1 % $num2;
    } 
}
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST"  action="#">
        <input type="number" id="num1" name="num1" value="<?=$num1?>" >
        <select name="operacion" id="operacion" name="operacion" value="<?=$operacion?>">
            <option disabled selected>Operacion</option>
            <option value="+" <?php if ($operacion=='+') {echo 'selected';} ?>>+</option>
            <option value="-" <?php if ($operacion=='-') {echo 'selected';} ?>>-</option>
            <option value="*" <?php if ($operacion=='*') {echo 'selected';} ?>>*</option>
            <option value="/" <?php if ($operacion=='/') {echo 'selected';} ?>>/</option>
            <option value="%" <?php if ($operacion=='%') {echo 'selected';} ?>>%</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2" value="<?=$num2?>" >
        <input type="submit" name="enviar">
        <input type="number" name="resultado" id="resultado" value="<?=$resultado?>" disabled>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Imagino que esta respuesta la basaste en la respuesta de @franmost (esta respuesta fue casi un cuarto de hora después que la suya). Si es así deberías indicarlo en la respuesta (o borrarla) y, además, deberías marcar su respuesta como correcta para dar por cerrada esta pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Basta con modificar esta parte de tu código:

```
<input type="number" name="resultado" id="resultado"
  value="<?= isset($resultado)?htmlspecialchars($resultado):'0' ?>"
  disabled /><br><br>
```

Agregando el contenido de `$resultado` al atributo `value` del input podrás mostrar lo que has calculado.

Comment: muchas gracias. isset($resultado) Me ha funcionado para añadir una memoria